# Changing from rectangular coordinates to spherical coordinates (integration)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I am taking calculus 3 and I have problems understanding how to change from rectangular coordinates to spherial ones (integration).

For example, I have this problem:

Find the volume of the solid $T$ enclosed by the surface:

$$(x^2 + y^2 +z^2)^2 = 2z(x^2 + y^2)\;.$$

How I change to spherical ones? Can someone resolve this one explaining it step by step??

Also if someone know a place in the web to learn this it will be appreciated!
Thanks!!

Comment: [What a nice shape.](http://i.imgur.com/L9B2jP0.png)

Comment: edit: Just how to set up the limits, do not have to integrate it!

Comment: Take a look at Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, Theorem 15.10, Example 2. He gives the full explanation. This is around page 507.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates#Coordinate_system_conversions).  You have $x=r \sin \theta \cos \phi, y=r \sin \theta \sin \phi, z= r\cos \theta$  The volume element is $r^2 \sin \theta dr\;d\theta\; d\phi$  Your equation becomes $r^4=2r^3 \cos \theta \sin^2 \theta$ by plugging in the expressions.

Comment: yes but, how I find the limits of integration?

Comment: @Edwardo $\phi$ is $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\theta$ is $0$ to $\frac \pi 2$ as the part from $\theta=\frac \pi 2$ to $\pi$ is a duplicate when you revolve in $\phi$  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3Dcos%28theta%29*sin^2%28theta%29%2C+theta+from+0+to+pi) is a plot with $z$ to the left